# Two different UITableViewCells with same xib

Tags: ios, swift

I have two UITableViewCells that looks **exactly the same**, but each one has a completely different logic.
So I want to create two UITableViewCell, with the same xib.

The logic of each cell is different and I don't want to have code split with `if`s.

How do I do that?

Comment: @the4kman you're link does not answer my question. It's not a dup.

Comment: How come? It deals with the exact same problem.

Comment: My question is not about subclass...

Answer (score 0):

If its a same UI than you shouldn't create two UITableViewCell.

What you can do it write two different updateView method in a same uitableview class.

This way you can reuse the code and also if there is design change you just need to change in one place

Comment: That's not going to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you please give some more details of your problem?

Comment: What you're suggesting is to have one class with all the code in it. Exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You can still create one class and create two different protocols. and you class should confirm that two protocols.
This way you can separate your logical part

Comment: Create a protocol for viewModel with a property say valueToBeDisplayed . Create 2 viewModels implementing the above protocol. Say in one cell you want to display firstName and in second cell you want to display lastName. So viewModels can have a property valueToBeDisplayed and assign respective values to respective models.  Cells should have a property of this viewModelProtocol. In cellForRowAtIndexPath method assign the viewModel to ur cell. In cell just set the valueToBeDisplayed to your label.